# Cross-platform 3D game engine for hobbyist developers?

Tags: 3d, cross-platform, game-engine

I'm trying to find an engine to make a very simple 3D game for Windows, Android, and iOS.  There are a number of such things out there (Unity, ShiVa, SIO2, etc), but they all seem to be targeted at development companies with a budget.  Accordingly, they are all very expensive from the perspective of an individual hobbyist developer.  They also have a great many features that I have no need of.

I'm wondering if there's a much more basic product out there that's in the sub-$100 range and doesn't require a subscription.  I really only need primitive shapes, simple textures, and basic lighting.  So I don't need a pile of features, but I do want a polished development experience and reliable support.  Something with a high-level language that compiles to native binaries would be ideal, but not required.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What language do you wish to use?

Comment: I'm not too picky.  I've worked with enough languages that the differences are mostly just syntax for me.  Something easy like Lua or Python would be great and I'd prefer to stay away from nuts-n-bolts things like C++, but I could work with most anything.

Comment: @TrickyWidget, which engine you decided to use?

Answer (score 7):

I've been pretty impressed with the new Gameplay engine: http://www.gameplay3d.org/. It's open source under the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html), and is being actively developed. It supports OSX, Win, iOS, Android and BB10 (new BlackBerry platform).

I found it great for a rapid prototype BB10 app I did [[youtube]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jof8zJ0isjI). It's a thin, lightweight and quite well-written for the relatively early stage of development it is at. It has all the basic stuff you need like Vector classes, meshes, vertex buffers, and a scene graph system. Material, shader and texture support were my favorite parts - super fast to get up and running, and easy to define/load all three using gameplay material files. It also includes a decent UI system including a simple but expressive UI markup language. The devs are very responsive to bug reports.

Downsides are that it isn't super mature yet, but definitely solid enough for hobbyist stuff. The Vector/Math libs also aren't very optimised yet, although there are a couple of NEON vector optimisations in. It also uses refcounting for most resources which I'm not a huge fan of. But overall, I think it is quite awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Unity3D has two versions: "Completely Free" & "Very Expensive." The free version will do everything you need and more. The paid version is for development companies like mine, but even we only have a few licensed computers. Most of us build our apps almost totally in the free version until the very end when we need the special features to compile for the Apple Store etc. I've found Unity very intuitive, and the ease with which you can turn your project into a playable .exe is amazing - a single click. They have a pretty decent scripting reference, and a wiki called Unify. In the language department I would recommend C#, but JavaScript/UnityScript will do all the same things. It's a preference issue. Good luck whatever you choose!

Comment: Unfortunately, the mobile extensions (as I mentioned I require) cost $800.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in Javascript and web graphics, [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is a good light-weight cross-platform 3D library. It's open-source as well, so there is no subscription/payment/etc.

Comment: I'm looking to build stand-alone apps (something I could put in the mobile markets, for example), but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the OP is looking for an engine, not a 3D graphics library (a la OpenGL/Direct3D).

Answer (score 1):

Two graphic engines that haven't been mentioned are [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org) and [IrrlIcht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net). The game engine [GameKit](https://code.google.com/p/gamekit) has an adapter kit for both the 3d engines.

You can find many other engines at the [Gamekit "Related works" wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/gamekit/wiki/Related_Work) and at [Wikipedia "List of game engines" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines), check the "Target platform" column.

Answer (score 0):

The [Axiom 3D Rendering Engine](http://axiom3d.net) has support for many platforms and various GFX APIs, including Windows Phone 7, Windows, iPhone, Android, Linux and Mac OSX, using OpenGL, OpenGL ES, DirectX and XNA. You'll need licenses for MonoTouch and/or Mono For Android from Xamarin to write and deploy to iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Irrlicht 3d Engine is full open source good and free

Proton 3d Engine kernel use Irrlicht and Bullet Physics, also full open source

Build on Win32 Macox Linux Android Ios

try this
https://github.com/fatalfeel/proton_sdk_source

and
svn://rtsoft.com/rtsvn/proton

and
svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/irrlicht/code/branches/ogl-es