# Choosing 3D Engine for iOS in C++

Tags: c++, ios, 3d, marmalade

Good day.

Currently I'am looking for 3D engine for iOS written on C++ as powerful as Marmalade and I don't know which to choose.

Why C++? I need it to be crossplatform (for future plans).
Why not Marmalade? If I'll use Marmalade it means that I can't anymore use my favorite Objective-C libraries and frameworks. I want to make interface/network/all using XCode and just one screen will contain 3D scene (and I need to do many things here. Shaders, CSG, texture masking, boolean operations, procedural mesh generation, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is a pretty popular 3d engine for iOS. Check it out:
http://unity3d.com

You may also check out Cocos 3d which is an extension of Cocos 2d which is written in C++.
http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

You can also check out http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net

You may also find some information on these posts:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21/easy-to-use-cross-platform-3d-engines-for-c-game-development

[Cross-platform 3D game engine for hobbyist developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139580/cross-platform-3d-game-engine-for-hobbyist-developers)

Comment: Worth noting, that Unity3D for iOS is not free. Altho, that was not asked, but for one 3D filled scene, 400$ (at minimum) is kind of expensive.

Comment: Unity integration with existing iOS code just too bad. It doesn't allow me to load/unload Unity from memory whenever I want. If it loaded once - it can't be freed anymore. Cocos3d isn't crossplatform as far as I can see.

Comment: **psycketom**, not really. This 3D scene is a major part of our app. $400 is a really good price. But Unity isn't good enough for us.

Comment: @bobby: I just added some additinoal info to my answer.

Comment: Unity doesn't support C++. Cocos3d written in Objective-C (not C++)

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned Objective-C, I think I have to mention about this.
Currently as far as I know, three companies are trying to offer Objective-C based 3D engine on Android. By definition, it will be supported natively on iOS.

- http://www.yeecco.com/stella/features

  This company already released the product, but no sure about stability or range of supported devices. It's pretty sure that this is supporting Samsung devices because they are sponsored by Samsung. Location or developers are unknown, and also no showcases.
- http://www.apportable.com

  This company has no release yet, but very promising. As you can see, they listed several famous iOS games ported to Android by their beta product. Also, they have more information on their website.
- http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ko/juice

  Marmalade has also released an iOS to multiple platforms (including Android) tool called Juice, that makes Objective-C games run on Android.

Comment: Wow! Never though that was possible!